# Setting NSDocumentDirectory so it doesn't backup to iCloud

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

I'm trying to mark the entire folder of my app's NSDocumentDirectory so that it is excluded from the iCloud backup, but when I go to the terminal and run: xattr -plxv com.apple.MobileBackup  I get this error: No such xattr: com.apple.MobileBackup

Thank you in advance for any help offered.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions 
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *pathURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirectory];

    [self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:pathURL];
}

- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) { // iOS <= 5.0.1
        const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

        const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;
    } else { // iOS >= 5.1

        NSLog(@"%d",[URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil]);
        return [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How can you run Terminal on your iOS app's folder? You mean in the Simulator?

For sure Apple is going to ignore or strip out that attribute from the primary Documents folder. What you should do is what Apple tells developers to do (from [File Systems Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)):

> Handle support files—files your application downloads or generates and can recreate as needed—in one of two ways:
>
> - In iOS 5.0 and earlier, put support files in the *<Application_Home>*`/Library/Caches` directory to prevent them from being backed up
> - In iOS 5.0.1 and later, put support files in the *<Application_Home>*`/Library/Application Support` directory and apply the com.apple.MobileBackup extended attribute to them. This attribute prevents the files from being backed up to iTunes or iCloud. If you have a large number of support files, you may store them in a custom subdirectory and apply the extended attribute to just the directory.

So you create a new directory for your files inside `Application Support`, and apply the attribute to that directory.

**EDIT:** Well, it seems that info is out of date and the document has not been updated. From the [iOS 5.1 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_1/_index.html):

> iOS 5.1 introduces a new API to mark files or directories that should
>   not be backed up. For `NSURL` objects, add the
>   `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute to prevent the corresponding
>   file from being backed up. For `CFURLRef objects`, use the corresponding
>   `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute.
>
> Apps running on iOS 5.1 and
>   later must use the newer attributes and not add the
>   `com.apple.MobileBackup` extended attribute directly, as previously
>   documented. The `com.apple.MobileBackup` extended attribute is
>   deprecated and support for it may be removed in a future release.

It turns out that you can get actual code to do this in the [Technical Q&A QA1719](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html).

Also, I found I need to create the Application Support directory, at least in the Simulator. Hope this code helps:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // got to make sure this exists
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *appSupportDir = [self applicationAppSupportDirectory];
    if(![manager fileExistsAtPath:appSupportDir]) {
        __autoreleasing NSError *error;
        BOOL ret = [manager createDirectoryAtPath:appSupportDir withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
        if(!ret) {
            LTLog(@"ERROR app support: %@", error);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    ...
}

- (NSString *)applicationAppSupportDirectory
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

Comment: But the /Library/Application Support directory can be deleted by the system?

Comment: My app has code in it now to create it if its not there. That said, I seriously doubt Apple would delete that folder when they are telling us to use it. The docs never really say whether its suppose to already be there or you should create it - one would assume it would already be created but in my usage in the Simulator the folder was not there.

Comment: Yes, the folder is not there unless you create it, but I'm talking about the system deleting files there in case of low memory (like on caches folder). I want persistent image downloads in my app for offline use, and I'm not sure if I should store them in the NSDocumentDirectory or NSApplicationSupportDirectory. (I'm using the do not backup for iCloud)

Comment: Just re-read Apple's statements on this in their File System memo an the tech note. They tell you over and over if you have files you need to keep around - files that should NOT get deleted - to put them in that folder and NOT the caches folder. Don't take my word for it read their docs directly. It would be unthinkable for Apple to tell you to save essential information in some directory, then go and delete that info later on.

Comment: OK. From ios Data Storage guidelines: "4. Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because customers expect it to be available during offline use. This attribute works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in, including the Documents directory. These files will not be purged and will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup."

Comment: The "including the Documents directory" made me doubt, but now I have clear that the files won't be deleted in the NSApplicationSupportDirectory if I mark them with the do not backup, thanks David H

Comment: OK. To sum up. "Application Support directory" would not be deleted except you manually do so. Willing that directory not to be back up by iCloud or iTunes, I must set the attribute to that directory. Am I correct? Is setting attribute a must?

Comment: Its unthinkable that Apple would go and delete this folder but there is nothing to stop them - I have not read anything that they say they promise not to do it. That said, as I said earlier in this thread, its unthinkable they would do this - blow users content away. Regarding backups, the full directory will get backed up, assuming there is content that does NOT have the "do-not-back-this-up" marker - content that can be a file or folder with files in it.